# How to authenticate and authorize with AWS Identity and Access Management?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-iam

I am writing my own reporting software in Java and planning to use RDS for data storage. I want to do the A.A. with AWS IAM.  Is there any example(s) of authenticating and authorizing with AWS Identity and Access Management that you might be aware and share with me?

I am not looking on how to set up the user from Amazon's console or how to issue console commands.  Instead I would like to see some Java code how to identify if user is authenticated with his/her credentials (user id, password combination) and whether that person authorized to get access to specific report.

Comment: I don't see one on the AWS website, although there are several code samples out there.  Why don't you show us what you've tried so far, and how you are stuck?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#How_do_I_get_started_with_IAM says: *To start using IAM, you must subscribe to at least one of the AWS services that has integrated with IAM. Then you can create and manage users, groups and permissions via IAM APIs, Command Line Tools, or via the IAM console which gives you a point-and-click, web-based interface. You can also use the AWS Policy Generator to create policies.*

Answer (score 1):

AWS IAM is not designed to authenticate users with your own app. AWS IAM is designed to authenticate users with *AWS services*.

The only way to see if a user is a real user(authentication) and if that user is authorized is to actually make an AWS API call.

For example, you can create a policy that looks like this and attach it to a user/group:

```
{
   "Statement":[{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":["rds:CreateDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:DeleteDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:DescribeDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
                "rds:RevokeDBSecurityGroupIngress"],
      "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

And the user or group who has this policy can only make these API calls and not others.

See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.html

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has something called Cognito which is designed to sync application profiles across mobile devices. What applies to your question, though, is that it also allows users to authenticate with Google, Facebook, or Amazon (it uses OAuth).

http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/